# Question about the definition of an open map

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a map. If $U \subset X$ is open $\implies$ $f(U) \subset Y$ open in $Y$, then $f$ is an open map.

If we have $U \subset X$ open in $X$ $\implies$ $f(U)$ is open and closed in $Y$. Do we call $f$ an open map?

Comment: Then $f$ would be an open map with an additional property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is open as a map, because it sends open sets to open sets. The fact that the image of an open set is also closed does not change that fact - openness and closedness are not mutually exclusive conditions.